# ID not being passed in RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache2

I am facing an issue while using .htaccess.The Re write rule is as follows.

```
RewriteRule ^user/([a-z]+)/?$ user.php?id=$1
```

incoming url : http://abhimanyu.localhost.com/user/home/
its redirecting to user.php but i am not getting the id.
e.g $id= $_GET['id'];

any idea why???

FYI the re write logs

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2011:23:38:35 +051800] [abhimanyu.localhost.com/sid#b8b34860][rid#b8d34d28/subreq]
(1) [perdir
/home/administrator/public_html/abhimanyu/]
pass through
/home/administrator/public_html/abhimanyu/user.php
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2011:23:38:35 +051800] [abhimanyu.localhost.com/sid#b8b34860][rid#b8d21ce0/initial]
(3) [perdir
/home/administrator/public_html/abhimanyu/]
add path info postfix:
/home/administrator/public_html/abhimanyu/user.php
-> /home/administrator/public_html/abhimanyu/user.php/home
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2011:23:38:35 +051800] [abhimanyu.localhost.com/sid#b8b34860][rid#b8d21ce0/initial]
(3) [perdir
/home/administrator/public_html/abhimanyu/]
strip per-dir prefix:
/home/administrator/public_html/abhimanyu/user.php/home
-> user.php/home
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2011:23:38:35 +051800] [abhimanyu.localhost.com/sid#b8b34860][rid#b8d21ce0/initial]
(3) [perdir
/home/administrator/public_html/abhimanyu/]
applying pattern '^user/([a-z]+)/?$'
to uri 'user.php/home'
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2011:23:38:35 +051800] [abhimanyu.localhost.com/sid#b8b34860][rid#b8d21ce0/initial]
(1) [perdir
/home/administrator/public_html/abhimanyu/]
pass through
/home/administrator/public_html/abhimanyu/user.php
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2011:23:38:35 +051800] [abhimanyu.localhost.com/sid#b8b34860][rid#b8d2cd08/subreq]
(1) [perdir
/home/administrator/public_html/abhimanyu/]
pass through
/home/administrator/public_html/abhimanyu/home
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([a-z]+)$ user.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if you're trying to capture the string immediately after `/user/` or after `/user/home`. If you need to capture both, try this:

`^user/([a-z]+)/(.+)$`

You can access the first string after user with `$1` and the second string with `$2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the `MultiViews` option.